# What is the correct way to get the iOS Library folder using Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

This will get me my iOS app's document root:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Is there something similar to get to the **Library** folder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var docsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var libPath = Path.Combine (docsPath, "..", "Library");
```

Comment: And if Apple changes the location of the Library folder tomorrow, then...?

Comment: then every applications will be broken because Apple documents this and does not provide an API to retrieve the directory. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: I think iOS 8 has changed this.  Does anyone have an update for this?

Comment: @Lereveme The Xamarin APIs automatically check the OS version. The code above will work on all versions of iOS.

Comment: Hi @Krumelur - See the answer I submitted.  It comes from Xamarin's iOS file system help docs.

Comment: But the Library folder is not a child of Documents, it's on the same level, why should it be concatenated?

Comment: Since the path ends up always being relative to "another" folder (I use Personal->..->Library) - couldn't Xamarin just keep a special constant for Library? That way they would have the responsibility of updating it when Apple changes things instead of us..

Answer (score 9):

Currently (iOS 12) you can retrieve the **Library** path via:

```
var libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources);

".../APP-UUID/Library"
```

For directories nested within the Library folder, such as the local app cache, you can do:

```
var pathToCache = Path.Combine(libraryPath, "Caches"); 

".../APP-UUID/Library/Caches"
```

Additional directories on Xamarin IOS that may be of interest:

```
SpecialFolder.Favorites =   ".../APP-UUID/Library/Favorites"
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments = ".../APP-UUID/Documents"
SpecialFolder.MyMusic =     ".../APP-UUID/Documents/Music"
SpecialFolder.MyPictures =  ".../APP-UUID/Documents/Pictures"
SpecialFolder.MyVideos =    ".../APP-UUID/Documents/Videos"
SpecialFolder.Desktop =     ".../APP-UUID/Documents/Desktop"
```

More options can be explored on the [Xamarin Docs for File System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system)

Comment: The current answers are a few years old, and while they were helpful, I figured I would share my latest findings with everyone.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS8 I used this and it worked:

```
NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls (NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0].Path
```

I got this from Xamarin's [page about the iOS file system](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/).  It says "iOS 8 NOTE: parts of this document are affected by changes in iOS 8. If your application uses Environment.SpecialFolder or calculates relative paths like "../Documents" you should read this tech note from Apple. Updated information is also available at iOS File System Basics."

Comment: I couldn't find this code on the link you shared. Also your explanation is really vage. I couldn't understand it.